# pandas group by time interval

Tags: python, pandas-groupby

I would like to group by 1 minute interval, however, some of data reading's timestamp will be 5 minute interval. Will this group by automatically ignore 5 minute interval data or should I remove 5 minute interval recordings?

```
grouped_minutely_id = df_sample.set_index('captureTime', drop=False, inplace=False)
grouped_minutely_id = grouped_minutely_id.groupby([pd.Grouper(freq='1Min'), 'id'])

id      captureTime     sid occ         power   temp
3903    6/26/17 6:50    506 1.08E+17    21.48   73.68
3906    6/26/17 6:50    461 0           1.2     69.36

3923    6/26/17 6:51    461 9.62E+11    8.64    70.8
```

Comment: Have you tried anything (hint: `pd.TimeGrouper`)? And yes, don't mix your timescales! Remove the 5 min recordings.

Comment: Yes, I am trying `grouped_minutely_id = grouped_minutely_id.groupby([pd.Grouper(freq='1Min'), 'id'])`

Comment: @Alexander Also, I don't have readings every minute, some sensors reported at 10:00:00 and no readings for 10 minutes, then there's going to be a reading at 10:10:00. Will this be okay to apply group by?

Comment: Depending what the data is, you may wish to forward fill the values.

Comment: @Alexander I've ran group by and it seems it is complaining about data type. `ValueError: data type <type 'numpy.int64'> not inexact`. Is there anything wrong with my code? Code has been updated to my problem question.